# Load OpenCV's ML (SVM) from string

Tags: android, c++, ios, opencv, machine-learning

I'm currently developing an algorithm for texture classification based on Machine Learning, primarily Support Vector Machines (SVM). I was able to gain some very good results on my test data and now want to use the SVM in productive environment.

Productive in my case means, it is going to run on multiple Desktop- and Mobile platforms (i.e. Android, iOS) and always somewhere deep down in native threads. For reasons of software structure and the platform's access policies, I'm not able to access the file system from where I use the SVM. However, my framework supports reading Files in an environment where access the file system is granted and channel the file's content as a *std::string* to the SVM-part of my application.

The standard procedure how to configure an SVM is by using filenames and OpenCV reads directly from the file:

```
cv::SVM _svm;
_svm.load("/home/<usrname>/DEV/TrainSoftware/trained.cfg", "<trainSetName>");
```

I want this (basically reading from the file somewhere else and passing the file's content as a string to the SVM):

```
cv::SVM _svm;
std::string trainedCfgContentStr="<get the content here>";
_svm.loadFromString(trainedCfgContentStr, "<trainSetName>") // This method is desired
```

I couldn't find anything in OpenCV's docs or source that this is possible somehow, but it wouldn't be the first OpenCV-Feature that's there and not documented or widely known. Of course, I could hack the OpenCV source and cross-compile to each of my target platforms, but I'd try to avoid that since it is a hell lot of work, besides I'm pretty convinced I'm not the first one with this problem.

All ideas (also unconventional) and/or hints are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as long as you stick with the c++ api it's quite easy, FileStorage *can* read from memory:

```
string data_string; //containing xml/yml data
FileStorage fs( data_string, FileStorage::READ | FileStorage::MEMORY);
svm.read(fs.getFirstTopLevelNode()); // or the node with your trainset
```

(unfortunately not exposed to java)

Comment: Brilliant, that works fine for me. Just a note, at least with my old OpenCV 2.4.6 you have to use the overloaded * operator to get the svm.read to work: `FileStorage fs (data_string, FileStorage::READ | FileStorage::MEMORY); _svm.read(*fs,*fs.getFirstTopLevelNode());`